# ENOENT Error when trying to install Angular CLI on Windows

Tags: node.js, angular, windows, npm

I've been trying for sometime and after exploring many replies around the web I can't solve this.

I'm trying

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

and I'm getting:
[image]

Npm -v = 7.7.6
Node -v = 15.13.0

Edit: I fixed it, the problem was that I had to remove the semi-colon from the "ComSpec" property as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Try --force flag `npm install -g @angular/cli --force`

Comment: @OwenKelvin, that didn't work :(

Comment: The path to `node.exe` seems corrupt (notice the extra slash) - it might be a problem with your node/npm installation.
Does this occur only if you try to install `@angular/cli`? Can you install any other packages?

Comment: @zwif I had noticed that and removed the slash from my path. Also installed making sure there was no slash and when I run it the slash is still there. Any hints?

Comment: Also, I tried installing Ionic using npm and it installed fine. Weird?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, the problem was that I had to remove the semi-colon from the "ComSpec" property as shown below:

[image]